# $A$ is diagonalizable iff the sum of dimensions of the eigen spaces of $A$ is $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification

**Notation**

Let $F$ be a field, and let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(F)$ be the space of $n$ by $n$ matrices over $F$. Say that $A$ is diagonalizable provided that there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}AS$ is diagonal.

Let $\ker(A-\lambda_jI)$ denote the eigen space of $A$ for eigen value $\lambda_j$ and $\mathcal{B}(\ker(A-\lambda_jI))$ denote a basis for the eigen space of $A$ corresponding to eigen value $\lambda_j$.

**Goal**

I already have that $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if there exists an eigen basis of $F^n$ consisting of eigen vectors of $A$. I want to show that $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if the sum of the dimensions of the eigen spaces of $A$ is equal to $n$.

**Attempt**
Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $A\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(F)$.

$\Longrightarrow$ Suppose that $A$ is diagonalizable. Then there is an eigen basis $(\vec{v}_i:i\in\mathbb{N}_n)$ of $A$. Suppose there are $1\leq k\leq n$ eigen values of $A$. Say that two eigen vectors in the eigen basis are related if and only if they have the same eigen value. This forms an equivalence relation on the eigen basis from $A$, whose equivalence classes are denoted $[\vec{v}]_{\lambda_j}$. We claim that the set of elements in $[\vec{v}]_{\lambda_j}$ forms a basis for the eigen space $\ker(A-\lambda_jI)$. The vectors in $[\vec{v}]_{\lambda_j}$ are linearly independent and eigen vectors of $A$ corresponding to eigen value $\lambda_j$. We need only show that they span $\ker(A-\lambda_jI)$. Let $\vec{x}\in\ker(A-\lambda_jI)$. Write $\vec{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\vec{v}_i$. Then $$(A-\lambda_jI)(\vec{x})=\sum_{\vec{v}_i\not\in[\vec{v}]_{\lambda_j}}a_i\lambda_j\vec{v}_i = \vec{0}$$ Since the remaining vectors in the above sum are linearly independent, then all of the corresponding scalars $a_i=0$. This means that $\vec{x}=\sum_{\vec{v}_i\in[\vec{v}]_{\lambda_j}}a_i\vec{v}_i$ so $[\vec{v}]_{\lambda_j}$ spans $\ker(A-\lambda_jI)$, hence $\dim\ker(A-\lambda_jI)=|[\vec{v}]_{\lambda_j}|$. Now the sum of the dimensions of all eigen spaces of $A$ is $n$, since the equivalnce relation partitions the initial eigen basis into a disjoint union of $k$ subsets.

I would like to know if the proof of this is good, or if there is any more efficient way to go about this proof. Any hints on the other direction would be appreciated too. Thanks.

Comment: A hint for the other direction: Show that two distinct eigenspaces intersect trivially, i.e., the intersection is $\{0\}$. Use this to conclude that if $B_1, \ldots, B_k$ are bases for the different eigenspaces, then $B_1 \sqcup \cdots \sqcup B_k$ is still linearly independent. By counting the number of vectors, you are now done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to summarize what you are trying to prove is to notice of the well known fact that eigenspaces are a direct sum. If you don't know how to prove it, start thinking why eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues must be linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks. That was kind of what I was thinking of doing. I would have to think more about why eigen vectors corresponding to different eigen values must be linearly independent, but I have a pretty clear idea on how to show that they are linearly independent using definitions