# Conditions for diagonalizability of a linear transformation T

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Given an n-dimensional vector space V, a linear transformation $T\colon V\rightarrow V$, with a list of distinct eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^k$. Given a fixed eigenvalue $\lambda$, such that the eigenspace of $\lambda\ E_{\lambda}$ has dimension n-k+1, prove that T is diagonalizable.

I'm trying to prove that there exists a basis $\beta\subseteq V$ such that $\forall w_i\in \beta,\ \sum a_iT(w_i)=\lambda \sum a_iw_i$ for a collection of n scalars $a_i$ (I understand that is the definition of diagonizability).

So far I have the following:

Let $dim(E_{\lambda}):= p$. So $n=p+k-1$. So, given a basis $\gamma\subseteq E_{\lambda}\implies\forall u\in E_{\lambda}, \gamma_i\in\gamma,\sum_{i=1}^p c_iT(\gamma_i)=\lambda\sum_{i=1}^pc_i\gamma_i$.

Now, given a vector and basis $v\in V, \beta\subseteq V$ respectively, $\forall w_i\in\beta,\ T(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iT(w_i)=\sum_{i=1}^p a_iT(w_i)+\sum_{i=p+1}^n a_iT(w_i)$

So far, my guess is, given a coordinate change, we can send $T(\gamma)$ to $T(\beta)$ such that we can make the following substitution:

$$T(v)=\lambda\sum_{i=1}^p a_iw_i+\lambda\sum_{i=p+1}^n a_iw_i$$

Thus finishing the proof, but I don't know why should the size of the base of the eigenspace be p for it to work (if it does work), or why should the base of V be a function of the amount of eigenvalues and the dimension of the eigenspace of one of those eigenvalues.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your guess is weird: it seems to mean that $E_\lambda=V.$

Comment: I don't understand why should the dimension of the eigenspace be n+1-k where k is the amount of eigenvalues of T. It seems arbitrary. It of course isn't the case that the eigenspace is V because the dimensions don't match, but so far it's the best I have

Comment: You wrote that each vector $w_i$ of the basis $\beta$ of $V$ satisfies $T(w_i)=\lambda w_i.$

Comment: Yes, that's a condition of diagonalization. The existence of a basis $\beta$ s.t that condition is met

Comment: No, it is not. That is a condition for $T=\lambda{\rm id}_V,$ which is much stronger than diagonalizability. Anyway, you did not prove that $\forall i\quad T(w_i)=\lambda w_i:$ you just claimed it.

Comment: Oh wait I just realized something. You missed the existence of scalars $a_i$ s.t. $\sum a_iT(w_i)=\lambda\sum w_i$, which is what I actually wrote. It is correct that I didn't prove the fact I stated but I didn't know how to prove it, hence my post.

Comment: I'm also confused as to what's the difference between the condition you wrote and the one I wrote. Why aren't they equivalent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140808/discussion-between-eduardo-v-kuri-and-anne-bauval).

Comment: I already did, but found something that isn't clear to me. I already posted a comment

Answer (score 1):

Assume your $k$ eigenvalues are numbered in such a way that the first one is this particular $\lambda,$ and denote by $p_1=n-k+1,p_2,\dots,p_k$ the dimensions of the corresponding eigenspaces. Since $p_2,\dots,p_k\ge1,$
$$\sum_{i=1}^kp_i\ge n-k+1+(k-1)\cdot1=n,$$
which is a (necessary and) [sufficient condition of diagonalizability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4103370).

Comment: https://www.nibcode.com/en/linear-algebra/diagonalization according to this post (haven't done the proof myself), the sum of dimensions of eigenspaces should be equal to n. Not greater than or equal. Is it wrong?

Comment: It is always $\le n,$ so proving equality is equivalent to proving it is $\ge n.$

Comment: Okay. I'd also like to know what's the difference between stating that $T(v)=\lambda v$ and $T=\lambda Id_v$. Thanks a lot

Comment: $T=\lambda Id_V$ means $T(v)=\lambda v$ for *every* vector $v\in V$ (or equivalently, for every vector of some basis of $V$), which is not the case here.

Comment: But if it isn't the case, can T still be diagonizable? Isn't the first equivalence a condition for diagonizability?

Comment: No, e.g. the projection $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2,\;(x,y)\mapsto(x,0)$ is diagonalizable but is not a homothety.

Comment: So all transformations that meet $T=Id_V$ are diagonizable, but the opposite isn't true?

Comment: Also, the sum of the dimensions equals the dimension of the sum iff the sum of the spaces is a direct sum, but for it to be a direct sum T has to be diagonizable, didn't you miss to prove the sum of eigenspaces is direct without assuming the thing you need to prove?

Comment: A sum of eigenspaces is *always* direct, without $T$ to be necessarily diagonalizable. As for your previous question, look at my example above.

Comment: This is confusing me a bit, where did you get the definition of diagonizability that you're using? Also, the condition of direct sum only applies for distinct eigenvalues, right?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Anne Bauval's answer.

Since we concluded that $$\dim(E(\lambda_1,T)+\dots+E(\lambda_k, T))\ge n$$

We know that $\dim(E(\lambda_1,T)+\dots+E(\lambda_k, T))=n$ as $E(\lambda_1,T)+\dots+E(\lambda_k,T)$ is a subspace of $V$ and thus can't have dimension greater than $n$. Which implies that $E(\lambda_1,T)+\dots+E(\lambda_k, T)=V$

A basis of $E(\lambda_1,T)+\dots+E(\lambda_k, T)$(which is also a basis of $V$) consists of $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors of $T$. The matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is a diagonal matrix and thus $T$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: So two vector spaces are equal to each other if their dimensions match. Also, if the list has repeated eigenvalues, is the sum of eigenspaces still a direct sum?

Comment: @EduardoV.Kuri Yes. If the dimension of any subspace of $V$ is equal to the dimension of $V$, Then that subspace is equal to $V$. Also, the sum of eigenspaces is always a direct sum.

Comment: Where can I find the definition of diagonizability that you're using? Friedberg?

Comment: @EduardoV.Kuri The definition of diagonalizability that I am using is the standard definition of diagonalizability for a linear map. The two books I am aware of that use this definition are Linear Algebra Done Right and Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze. A [free pdf](https://linear.axler.net/Eigenvalues.pdf) of chapter $5$ of linear algebra done right is available on the authors website. Have a look at page $156$ for diagonalization of linear maps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm having trouble differentiating concepts

Comment: @EduardoV.Kuri No worries!